# Problems clearing logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I'm using the Android's log to supervise an application use, so I'm using logcat into the phone not in Eclipse.

Well, if I just write in the log and send me the information everything it's ok, but I receive information from previous executions. 
I decided to clear the log every time that my application starts, but now I usually lose the first log messages. Maybe logcat needs some time to get cleared? because when I try to do into debug everything it's ok.

Example:

> clear log, message 1, message 2, message 3, ...

Sometimes I don't receive message 1, sometimes don't receive 1 and 2...

I have checked all my code for possible accidental clears but I didn't find anything...

I call this function at the beginning (in onCreate())

```
public static void clearLog(){
            ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
            commandLine.add("logcat");
            commandLine.add("-c");//CLEAR

            Runtime process = Runtime.getRuntime();
            process.exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));

            TAG = "";
}
```

Then I add logs

```
log.i(TAG, "message1");
..
log.i(TAG, "messageN");
```

And this is how I collect the log:

```
ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
commandLine.add("logcat");
commandLine.add("-d");//dump and exit
commandLine.add("-v");//especify verbose mode
commandLine.add("raw");//raw show only the message, brief for show all
commandLine.add(TAG + ":V");//show TAG's log
commandLine.add("*:S");//hide others

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line, log = "";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    log += line + LINE_SEPARATOR;
}
```

Comment: Where have you put your "clear logs" code? Add some code to complete the question.

Comment: Added how I clear it, write and collect, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) for `exec()`:

> Executes the specified command and its arguments in a separate native process.

So it's running in a separate process. There's not really a good way to tell if it has finished before you start logging.

Instead of clearing the log, you could change the log TAG on each run. Just use the regular tag an append some number that identifies the run, even just a random one. Then when you collect your logs, you can filter by that, and only collect the ones you want.

Comment: Maybe you can filter by process id? Not sure on that one. Hope you get it worked out.

Comment: Finally I used a random tag and put the TAG that I need into the message. The proccess id is allways the same bacause the application is not destroyed at all sometimes, so doesn't work. Thank you!